# NSTimer Movement irregular

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I am trying to make a game movement animation in objective c so that when a button is pressed something will move across the screen while it is pressed. This works fine though the calling of the NSTimer which I am using is irregular and I am getting laggy movements. This is in iOS 6 so I wont use sprite kit as it is not available

Any suggestions on how to make it a regular call or to make it a smooth animation would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Here is the code:

```
-(void) click {
    if (!self.animating) {
        self.animating = YES;
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(move)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void) cancelClick {
    self.animating = NO;
    [timer invalidate];
}

-(void) move {
    CGPoint origin = self.target.frame.origin;
    if ([self.direction isEqual:@"left"]) {
        origin.x -= self.magnitude;
    } else if ([self.direction isEqual:@"right"]) {
        origin.x += _magnitude;
    } else if ([self.direction isEqual:@"up"]) {
        origin.y -= _magnitude;
    } else {
        origin.y += _magnitude;
    }
    [self.target move:0 toPoint:origin animated:YES delay:0 animationOptions:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear];
}
```

Comment: code for the object that uses NSTimer would be useful!

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin the code is now up there

Comment: NSTimer delays are really a best estimate kind of thing.  Take a look at CADisplayLink which also has the added advantage that it's synchronized with the display refresh, which in this case you want.

Comment: have you tried to setTolerance to 0 for the timer?

Comment: @David thank you so much this solved my issue completely